# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm, having an issue with my Firebase function. I'm getting the below error.

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

below is my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

sgMail.setApiKey(key);

export const weeklyReminder = functions.pubsub.schedule('every Wednesday 21:00').onRun(async context =>{

    const msg = {
        to: 'email@gmail.com',
        ...
    };
    return sgMail.send(msg);

});
```

How do you import into firebase functions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you using TypeScript or vanilla JavaScript? With plain JavaScript you'd use require like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Also, change the function to be the same as the below:

```
exports.weeklyReminder = functions.pubsub.schedule('every Thursday 21:00').onRun(
```

Comment: If you import it that way can you still use ”export const weeklyReminder” if not not do you export the function

Comment: Also using vanilla JavaScript

Comment: No you'd use:

exports.weeklyReminder = functions.pubsub.schedule('every Wednesday 21:00').onRun(async context =>{

Comment: @JasonByrne VS Code suggest to use ES module thus ended up with `import { region } from 'firebase-functions';`. Should we just ignore the suggestion?

Answer (score -2):

For me, I needed curly brackets around my instance, like so:

```
const { functions } = require('firebase-functions');
```

Otherwise I would get

```
TypeError: functions is not a function
```