# Cannot use import statement outside a module, TypeScript NodeJS Firebase Functions project

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I recently set up a Firebase Functions project using TypeScript. As far as I can tell I am using the same setup I have before in the past. This time, however, when I run `firebase emulators:start` I receive the following error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

<Local Computer Path>/firebase/functions/src/index.ts:3
import functions = require("firebase-functions");
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at loadModule (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/runtimes/node/triggerParser.js:10:16)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/runtimes/node/triggerParser.js:34:21
```

As far as I can tell I have not changed anything from past projects, where I did not come across this issue. The only potential difference I can think of is that I updated my firebase tools using `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`. Below are some of the files from my project:

src/index.ts

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import functions = require("firebase-functions");
import admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

...
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"],
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "module": "ES2020"
}
```

package.dev.json

```
{
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.js"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2020"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  ...
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

My `src/index.ts` import syntax matches what Google outlined in the Firestore documentation: [Import the required modules and initialize an app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app).

I have searched around for an answer but I have not come across one yet. Here are a few of the resources I have tried:

[SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module Firebase Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761839/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-firebase-functions)

[Node.js v13.14.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field)

[Typescript: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273824/typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the problem has a simple solution! The firebase emulators do not support typescript. To run functions in the emulator you first need to compile to JS (reference the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript)). Both `npm run serve` and `firebase deploy` will automatically transpile your code, `firebase emulators:start` does **NOT** do this automatically. When using the emulators you must first run `npm run build` in your functions folder.

Also note, in your package.json you need your `main` argument to reference the compiled JS code. I needed to update both my `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`. Below are the final versions:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use
`const functions = require("firebase-functions");` instead of
`import functions = require("firebase-functions");` - same for the 2nd import below it. The 'import' keyword can only be used with esmodules, while the const/require syntax is used in commonjs.

Comment: Ross thanks for the response. That fixed my issue with imports from node_modules. However that syntax isn't working when I try to import functions from another file: `const account = require("./account")`. This is what I am trying to achieve: [Group functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#group_functions)

Comment: Many thanks. Your advice worked for me. I was stuck with this issue for some time. Once I built the code to produce JS from TS using `npm run build` from the function folder, it fixed the issue. Firebase emulator booted up properly.

Before that I kept getting the following error but no longer now face the same issue

`import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I do not have the need to use `"type": "module" in package.json`. I am able to use imports like `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'`